# How do I SSH to my remote machine through another machine?

Tags: ssh, shell

I want to connect my remote machine via `ssh`, and I must connect to a proxy and in that proxy machine to connect my remote machine(remote machine is in the LAN of proxy machine, and it dosen't have a private ip address).

The following are my commands to connect my remote machine.

```
me@local_machine: ssh proxy # passwordless
proxy@proxy_machine: ssh my_remote_machine # passwordless
me@remote_machine:
```

How should I write a script in my local machine to connect my remote machine so that I don't need to type `ssh` command so many times to connect the remote machine.

I have a write a script in my local machine to connect the proxy, here show my code.

connect.sh

```
ssh -p 22022 proxy@proxy
```

But the above script is just connect the proxy machine, and in proxy machine, I still need to type `ssh` command to connect the remote machine.

What should I do, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
ssh -t user@proxy_machine "ssh user@remote_machine"
```

You need to use `-t` to allocate a pseudo-terminal or it will fail and complain about not having a terminal (varying message based on OS).